# Certificate (SHA1) loaded in a database but couldn't be found under SQL Configuration Manager and Key Registry

Tags: sql-server, encryption, certificate

**I have two instances on a server. sql 2014 (port 1433) and sql 2016 (port 50019)
I have a certificate with SHA1 algorithm  on a server that is not expired.**

[image]

****When sql server started I can clearly see that the above certificate was loaded for encryption (see snip).**

[image]

**Seems like this is NOT self generated certificate, as it doesn't say so.****

---

**However, if I check certificates under SQL configuration manager, I don't see it there.**

[image]

---

**Also, there is no certificates used under Register keys**

[image]

**So, why it's loaded in a database but can't be found under SQL Configuration and Register Editor?
Has it been installed correctly?**

Comment: Have you verified the thumbprint of the certificate is the one being loaded by SQL Server?

Comment: Yes. thumbprint  is verified. That is the one. Thank you

Comment: The thumbprint should always be in the registry. Maybe read through the following article to make sure you didn't miss anything.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

You can also verify within SQL that encryption is working.
SELECT encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@SPID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, why it's loaded in a database but can't be found under SQL Configuration and Register Editor?

By default, SQL Server will check the certificate store for any certificates that match the requirements to be used for SSL. If one is found then it is used in place of a self-seigned certificate which is generated upon startup (if needed).

Since this is done automagically for you, there is no configuration required, though it is best to be explicitly configured if forcing encryption.

There are various reasons it may not show up in the configuration manager for SQL Server. I've spent far too much time debugging these to know that previous to SQL Server 2019, it's a crap shoot at best.

> Has it been installed correctly?

It wouldn't be able to be used if it weren't.